# How to apply zoom effect on mouseover for all the images passed in a single Image tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to zoom images on mouseover but zoom is applied only on first image .

I am using given code in my django templates to zoom images .

```
{% for image in images_obj %}
    <img class="drift-demo-trigger" data-zoom="{% static 
    '/images/catalog/products/thumbnail/' %}{{image}}" src="{% static 
    '/images/catalog/products/thumbnail/' %}{{image}}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT"  
    style="width:99%;border:1px solid #ccc;">

    <div class="detail">                                            
       <section>                                                    
       </section>                                                                                    
    </div>
{% endfor %}

new Drift(document.querySelector('.drift-demo-trigger'), {
        paneContainer: document.querySelector('.detail'),
        inlinePane: 900,
        inlineOffsetY: -85,
        containInline: true,
        hoverBoundingBox: true
});
```

All images which are coming in loop should be zoomed but currently only the first image is able to zoom .

Answer (score 1):

Try this before ur html code:

```
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
}
.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<script>
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
</script>
```

Now in html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-12"style="margin-left: 0px">
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table-responsive">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div class="img-zoom-container">
<img id="myimage" src="{{ member.immagine.url }}" width="860" >
</div></td><td>
<div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<script>
// Initiate zoom effect:
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```